# setting my wordpress blog to display in an iframe only

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

im trying to have wordpress only display from a certain passed URL. (long story)

e.g i put this in the head and it works...mostly

```
<?php
$access="1uiydkdh7754jhdj";    
$access=$_GET['access'];   
if($access==0) {       
die('Im sorry you dont have permission to access
this page, please login and try again.');       
}
?>
```

so this work, but not very reliable, as I've had to add numerous other extras when the user clicks others pages, not efficient at all.

im new to php, is it possible to add a session into the header that basically does the above and will remember it for the whole duration of the site (including all links clicked and pages)?

Comment: Did you try using [Sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php)?

Comment: 1st line is useless. Plus, you should check `$access` with a better conditional clause, e.g. `if($access === 0) {`, if you really want to check if the value is 0 or not.

Comment: i would very much like to use sessions but im unsure how to accomplish this..can you supply an example?

Comment: @Shivan - the first line is not useless as the access is what is in the URL, hence decides if the site should show or not.

Comment: But the 2nd line already overwrite the value of `$access` without using it.

Comment: do you have any suggestions Shivan? on my issue? preferabliy using sessions so the a given url key will be remembered for the users duration on the site?